# Writing junit tests for Spring Kafka Configuration Classes?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, spring-kafka

I have a configuration class like below for my kafka consumer

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class ConsumerConfig{
   //some fields
   private Map<String, Object> getConfig(){
      //some kafka config in a map
      return map;
   }

   @Bean("consumerFactory")
   public ConsumerFactory<String, SomeClass> consumerFactory() {
      return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(this.getConfig());
   }
}
```

> I tried few tests by mocking some of the properties but all tests seem
> to fail. Is there any way i can create this ConsumerFactory bean by
> mocking the properties?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples of using mock consumers in the project's test suite. It is not trivial.

Alternatively, consider using the `MockConsumer` provided by the `kafka-clients` library.

Starting with version 3.0.7, Spring provides a `MockConsumerFactory` to serve up `MockConsumer`s. For earlier versions, you would have to mock the factory.